# Performing Viewshed Analysis for Transmission Line returns general error 999999?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, viewshed, error-999999

I have a scenario where a transmission line is designed and placed with heights for each structure.  With that being said, it is to be proposed to the forest service who is more concerned with how much of each structure can be seen from key observation points coupled with existing vegetation on the surface.

I do not have all of the data yet, but have been attempting to play around with the tools using a DEM and drawing in fictitious transmission lines.  I choose and observer point and am able to plug that and the raster in it, but no where do I see the third spot for the actual structures.  Not sure what I am missing and I have been combing through articles for quite a bit today.

I am using ArcGIS for desktop and have used the viewshed analysis and put in a DEM of the area as my input raster and an observation point for the input point. It returns back a "general error 99999" in the geoprocessing results table

Comment: 999999 errors have many causes as you can see from some of the previous Q&As here that are tagged with that: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-999999  I think it would help your question to attract potential answerers if you provide more detailed steps of precisely what you did prior to seeing this error, including the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you were using.

Answer (score 1):

You may have inconsistent coordinate systems.  As with any ArcGIS tool.  If your tool involves the interaction between raster and vector data, make sure both files reference the same coordinate system.  Reprojecting one of the datasets may solve your 99999 error problem.